# Java password checker boolean return values not working correctly

Tags: java

When I run this class through test cases, the code returns false every single time. I am assuming that this is because my flags are not working correctly in my helper methods since I set them all to false. However when I try to take them out, and replace them with just return true or return false, eclipse keeps telling me there is no return value. Do any of you see whats going wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
public static boolean isLevel1(String pwd) {
    int howMany = 0;
    if(isLongEnough(pwd) && hasNoSpaces(pwd)) {
        if(atLeastOneUpper(pwd)) howMany++;
        if(atLeastOneLower(pwd)) howMany++;
        if(atLeastOneDigit(pwd)) howMany++;
        if(howMany >= 2)
            return true;
    }
    return false;

}


public static boolean isLevel2(String pwd) {
    if(isLongEnough(pwd) &&
            hasNoSpaces(pwd) &&
            atLeastOneUpper(pwd) &&
            atLeastOneLower(pwd) &&
            atLeastOneDigit(pwd))
        return true;
    return false;
}   



private static boolean isLongEnough(String pwd) {
    if(pwd.length() >=6)
        return true;
    return false;
}

private static boolean hasNoSpaces(String pwd) {
    boolean flag = false;
    for(int i = 0; i<pwd.length(); i++) {
        if(!pwd.contains(" "))
            flag = true;
    }
    return flag;
}

private static boolean atLeastOneUpper(String pwd) {
    boolean flag = false;
    for(int i = 0; i<pwd.length(); i++) {
        if(Character.isUpperCase(i))
            flag = true;
    }
    return flag;
}

private static boolean atLeastOneLower(String pwd) {
    boolean flag = false;
    for(int i = 0; i<pwd.length(); i++) {
        if(Character.isLowerCase(i))
            flag = true;
    }
    return flag; 
}

private static boolean atLeastOneDigit(String pwd) {
    boolean flag = false;
    for(int i = 0; i<pwd.length(); i++) {
        if(Character.isDigit(i))
            flag = true;
}
    return flag;

}
```

}

Comment: Check each condition method individually to see if any one or more return an incorrect value

Comment: Most of the methods you use, you are using wrong. For example: `if(Character.isDigit(i))`: you check whether the character, represented by the ASCII-code `i` (which iterates from `0` to `pwd.length()`) is a digit. What you probably meant to check is whether the `i`-th character in `pwd` is a digit.

Comment: for the method `hasNoSpaces` . you don't need to put the `contains` method inside a loop. you don't need a loop at all in that case. All the methods below that can be optimised, i.e. as soon as the condition you're looking for is met, just return true and don't carry on checking.... Also make sure you're passing the correct characters when you call methods as such of `Character.isDigit` , `Character.isLowerCase` etc.

Comment: A remark: even if possible, you should not remove the `{` and `}` surrounding an `if`-body since it can lead to nasty bugs if you edit the code later. Overall, the problem seems to be too advanced for your current knowledge. Maybe you want to start with a simpler exercise.

Comment: that makes sense, thanks. I must have been in auto pilot mode writing the loops over and over

Comment: You can also simplify all the loops where you set `flag = true;` : as you check that there is at least one char matching the criteria, you could `return true;` instead of setting `flag = true;` and going on the next characters of your pass

Comment: It is completely off-topic for answering the question, but password strength checking by this means is considered to be a very bad practice.  Look into password entropy, with a dictionary checker (like cracklib's dictionary).  This kind of strength is not the kind that will protect you anymore.  That said, one of the most popular Google searches for password strength returns an algorithm like this one (that was not developed by researchers or tested against crackers). https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2016/08/18/nists-new-password-rules-what-you-need-to-know/  & https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

too late but you make error with Character.isXxxx(i) juste replace it by Character.isXxx(pwd.charAt(i))

```
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args){
        String password = "1Aallll";
        String l3password = "1A ";
        String l2password = "aAaaaaa";
        String l1password = "1Aallll";

        System.out.println("isLongEnough " + isLongEnough(password));
        System.out.println("hasNoSpaces " + hasNoSpaces(password));
        System.out.println("atLeastOneUpper " + atLeastOneUpper(password));
        System.out.println("atLeastOneLower " + atLeastOneLower(password));
        System.out.println("atLeastOneDigit " + atLeastOneDigit(password));

        System.out.println("isLevel1 " + isLevel1(l3password));
        System.out.println("isLevel1 " + isLevel1(l2password));
        System.out.println("isLevel1 " + isLevel1(l1password));

        System.out.println("isLevel2 " + isLevel2(l3password));
        System.out.println("isLevel2 " + isLevel2(l2password));
        System.out.println("isLevel2 " + isLevel2(l1password));
    }

    public static boolean isLevel1(String pwd) {
        int howMany = 0;
        if (isLongEnough(pwd) && hasNoSpaces(pwd)) {
            if (atLeastOneUpper(pwd)) {
                howMany++;
            }
            if (atLeastOneLower(pwd)) {
                howMany++;
            }
            if (atLeastOneDigit(pwd)) {
                howMany++;
            }
            if (howMany >= 2) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }

    public static boolean isLevel2(String pwd) {
        if (isLongEnough(pwd) && hasNoSpaces(pwd) && atLeastOneUpper(pwd) && atLeastOneLower(pwd) && atLeastOneDigit(pwd)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean isLongEnough(String pwd) {
        if (pwd.length() >= 6) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean hasNoSpaces(String pwd) {
        boolean flag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < pwd.length(); i++) {
            if (!pwd.contains(" ")) {
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }

    private static boolean atLeastOneUpper(String pwd) {
        boolean flag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < pwd.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(pwd.charAt(i))) {
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }

    private static boolean atLeastOneLower(String pwd) {
        boolean flag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < pwd.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isLowerCase(pwd.charAt(i))) {
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }

    private static boolean atLeastOneDigit(String pwd) {
        boolean flag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < pwd.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(pwd.charAt(i))) {
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        return flag;

    }
}
```

output :

```
isLongEnough true
hasNoSpaces true
atLeastOneUpper true
atLeastOneLower true
atLeastOneDigit true
isLevel1 false
isLevel1 false
isLevel1 true
isLevel2 false
isLevel2 true
isLevel2 true
```

2 methods can be simplify

```
    private static boolean isLongEnough(String pwd) {
    return pwd.length() >= 6;
}

private static boolean hasNoSpaces(String pwd) {
    return !pwd.contains(" ");
}
```